# Mongo Cluster - Unresponsive node/primary prevents creation of databases, secondary didn't take over

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo cluster with a few shards each backed by replicasets with a primary, a secondary and an arbiter.

Today one of the primaries became unresponsive. I logged into it directly and tried a "show dbs" but that appeared to hang. This worked fine on all other shards.

When I tried to create a database through a MongoS it would hang.

Why did the secondary not take over when the primary became unresponsive? Why would the cluster presumably try and create new databases on a non-responsive node?

Thanks!

Comment: without knowing why primary was non-responsive (i.e. anything in the logs? what does db.currentOp() show?) it's impossible to say, but it sounds like primary was still sending and acknowledging heartbeats so the other two nodes did not see the need to elect a new primary.

Comment: I've had this when some new large index was being built against extant data.